# Let $f:\Bbb R^2→\Bbb R:(0,0)\mapsto 0 \quad (x,y)\mapsto\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

> Let $$f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R:(0,0)\mapsto 0 \quad (x,y)\mapsto\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}$$
>
> i) Is $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$?
>   ii) Is $f$ differentiable at $(0,0)$?

I can prove that $f$ is homogeneous of degree $0$ and $f$ is not constant. So if I show that $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ exists, then I can prove i). How could about I prove this? And what about ii)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute the limits of $f(x,0)$ and $f(x,x)$ when $x\to0$. If these are different, then $f(x,y)$ has no limit when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$. In particular, the function $f$ cannot be continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Yeah, that is the right idea: $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x,x) = 1/2 \neq 0 = \lim_{x \to 0} f(x,0)$

Comment: Thanks, that makes life a lot easier!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: let $y=kx$, sub in $f$, and let $k$ vary.